# Why won't the BroadcastReceiver fail to start?

Tags: android, cordova, android-broadcast

I have an app with the following manifest entries.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.example.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="TestSmsApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.applegrew.cordova.android.plugin.SmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When my app is stopped and a new SMS is received, I see the following in logcat.

```
I/ActivityManager(  540): Start proc com.example.app for broadcast com.example.app/com.applegrew.cordova.android.plugin.SmsReceiver: pid=25457 uid=10095 gids={50095, 1028}
E/Trace   (25457): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

After that I see no more activity from my receiver. I also have a logger to print messages at the start of `onReceive()` but I guess that was never invoked. My receiver's code is as below.

```
package com.applegrew.cordova.android.plugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.LOG;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";

    private CallbackContext callback_receive;
    private boolean isReceiving = true;

    // This broadcast boolean is used to continue or not the message broadcast
    // to the other BroadcastReceivers waiting for an incoming SMS (like the native SMS app)
    private boolean broadcast = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
LOG.v("com.example.app", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>onReceive called!!!!");
        // Get the SMS map from Intent
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
           // Get received SMS Array
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get(SMS_EXTRA_NAME);

            for (int i=0; i < smsExtra.length; i++)
            {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);
                if(this.isReceiving && this.callback_receive != null) {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        obj.put(SMS.ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress());
                        obj.put(SMS.BODY, sms.getMessageBody());
LOG.v("com.example.app", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>with value" + sms.getOriginatingAddress() + ";; " + sms.getMessageBody());
                        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, obj);
                        result.setKeepCallback(true);
                        callback_receive.sendPluginResult(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            // If the plugin is active and we don't want to broadcast to other receivers
            // Also we cannot abort a broadcast which is not ordered.
            if (this.isReceiving && !broadcast && isOrderedBroadcast()) {
                this.abortBroadcast();
            }
         }
    }

    public void broadcast(boolean v) {
        this.broadcast = v;
    }

    public void startReceiving(CallbackContext ctx) {
        this.callback_receive = ctx;
        this.isReceiving = true;
    }

    public void stopReceiving() {
        this.callback_receive = null;
        this.isReceiving = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks good. Did you try to launch app in debug mode and put a breakpoint into onReceive() method?

Comment: @beworker Sorry can't do that I guess. Since it works fine if app is running. Once I close the app the debugger disconnects. To replicate the issue the app needs to started on receiving broadcast; and the debugger won't auto reconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried your code. It works well. `onReceive()` gets called, but the Application column is not filled in the LogCat. If you have filter set, you won't see the message. Please replace application filter with "tag:pdus" (or completely remove the filter) and you will see the output. Also use "Stop process" button in "Devices" view of Eclipse to stop the app.

Comment: Actually I am not using any filters on my logcat. I went back and checked out the full log but still I do not see the message.

Comment: Ok not sure what is the exact problem, but if log it as error instead of verbose then I can see the messages, even when there are no filters set!